# How to get list of all subfolders in one folder and write it to txt file using vb

Tags: vba, loops, directory, vb6

I want to know, how it possible to get list of all subfolders in "C/Windows" and write it to txt file. Here is my code:

```
Sub Check
MkDir "c:\New_Folder"

Dim iFileNo as Integer
Dim strFile As String
  strFile = "c:\New_Folder\data.txt" 'the file you want to save to
  intFile = FreeFile
  Open strFile For Output As #intFile
    Print #intFile, 
  Close #intFile

End Sub
```

Full Explanation: Write a program, like opening a folder on the D drive (the folder is your nickname). In this folder open the file data.txt, in which write down the names of all folders from the directory C: \ Windows. 2. Write a program that reads information from a file, which was opened with a first program and transfer through MsgBox skin another row to the file

Comment: Try Googling "+vb6 recursive folder listing" (without the quotes).

Comment: There is some methods how to get list of data, but problem is how to write it to txt file

Comment: The way of returning all subfolders from a folder is not complicated, but, in order to do that **from "C:/Windows"**, there are some subfolders which need special permissions, even if your user has administrative rights (Programs, LiveKernelReports etc.).

Comment: I need only names of folders and then write them to txt file

Comment: Even so, using iteration between folder subfolders (like: `For each subFld in folder.Subfolders`) will generate an error. It can be handled, making the function to also return the ones needing special permissions. Anyhow, Windows does a lot of subfolders and the code will take some time only to enumerate them. Why do you need it?

Comment: I've got this task from my teacher. Here is full description of the task, maybe it will help you to understand all: Write a program, like opening a folder on the D drive (the folder is your nickname). In this folder open the file data.txt, in which write down the names of all folders from the directory C: \ Windows.
2. Write a program that reads information from a file, which was opened with a first
program and transfer through MsgBox skin another row to the file

Comment: I guessed your questions must be homework! This isn't a forum for doing pupils homework for them. We can help correct errors in code you've posted here and suggest directions you might go to complete your task but writing the complete answer for you really won't help you learn!

Comment: Do you need only subfolders of Windows folder, not subfolders until the last level?

Comment: Only all subfolders from Windows directory

Comment: Then, it is easy. I will post an answer in two minutes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a problem is defined as "get list of all subfolders" and "write to a text file", I know I likely need to implement a loop of some kind.  As it turns out that is all that is missing from your code.  The `Dir` command can help solve this problem:

```
Private Sub Check()
   Dim intFile As Integer
   Dim strFile As String
   Dim FolderName As String
   
   MkDir "c:\New_Folder"
   strFile = "c:\New_Folder\data.txt"
   intFile = FreeFile
   Open strFile For Output As #intFile
   FolderName = Dir("c:\windows\", vbDirectory)
   
   Do While FolderName <> ""
      If FolderName <> "." And FolderName <> ".." And (GetAttr("c:\windows\" & FolderName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
         Print #intFile, FolderName
      End If

      FolderName = Dir()
   Loop
   
   Close #intFile
End Sub
```

I would also encourage you to use proper formatting of your code, in this case indentation.  It will make your life easier at some point!

Comment: I'm afraid that this code will return only the folders and files inside Window. No any child subfolders...

Comment: I've tried your code and it works, but it writes to data.txt only files from windows. How it possible to write name of folders which are inside windows directory?

Comment: @dextermikles  I have updated my answer to account for `vbDirectory` returning files **and** folders.  I've not used `Dir` in a long time and forgot the details of what it did.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the  next code:

```
Sub testGetSubFolders()
  Dim strFold As String, strFile As String, arrTxt
  strFold = "C:\Windows"
  If dir("c:\New_Folder", vbDirectory) = "" Then 'if the folder does not exist
     MkDir "c:\New_Folder"                       'it is created
  End If
  strFile = "c:\New_Folder\data.txt"
  arrTxt = GetSubFolders(strFold)     'receive an array of subfolders

  Open strFile For Output As #1
      Print #1, Join(arrTxt, vbCrLf) 'join the array on end of line
    Close #1
End Sub

Function GetSubFolders(strFold As String) As Variant 'it returns an array of subfolders path
   Dim fso, fldr, subFldr, arr, i As Long
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(strFold)
   ReDim arr(fldr.subFolders.count - 1)   'redim the array to keep the paths
     For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
         arr(i) = subFldr.Path: i = i + 1 'place the paths in the array and increment i
     Next subFldr
  GetSubFolders = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Getting error here: Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(strFold)

Comment: @dextermikles Please, use the updated code. I copied "C:/Windows" from your question, since it should be "C:\Windows". What is interesting, it works in my case with slash instead of backslash, too... What error still appear on that line, if any? Is it something connected to permissions?

Comment: Check my another question about vb6

Comment: @dextermikles I do not know where should I check for your "another question". But you did not answer my above question(s)...

Answer (score 0):

A basic example with no error checking:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim f
    For Each f In AllFolders("D:\Analysis")
        Debug.Print f
    Next f
End Sub

'return all folders which are subfolders of `startFolder`
Function AllFolders(startFolder As String)
    Dim col As New Collection, colOut As New Collection, f, sf
    
    col.Add startFolder
    Do While col.Count > 0
        f = col(1) & IIf(Right(f, 1) <> "\", "\", "")
        col.Remove 1
        sf = Dir(f, vbDirectory)                    'fetch folders also
        Do While Len(sf) > 0
            If GetAttr(f & sf) = vbDirectory Then   'is this a folder ?
                If sf <> "." And sf <> ".." Then    'ignore self or parent
                    col.Add f & sf & "\"            'add to list to check for subfolders
                    colOut.Add f & sf               'add to output
                 End If
            End If
            sf = Dir
        Loop
     Loop
     Set AllFolders = colOut
End Function
```

Comment: I thought that was already covered by others, hence my note about no error checking. 

Comment: Yes... I adapt it a little to return two arrays. One containing the required subfolders and the other the folders not being accessed because of permissions missing. If all subfolders are really necessary, I think the second array can be used to take the folders ownership and then giving all permissions, but I do not think it is safe to do it in Windows folder... Anyhow, this process can be done only in two steps. Firstly taking the ownership and only in a second step setting full permissions. At least, this is what I could do on the issue...